# phpunit - How to format output

Tags: formatting, phpunit, output

I want to format PHPUnit output like this:

```
1/15. ATestCaseTest ... passed (3/3), time: 0ms
  1/59. DISABLED_test1 ... skipped , time: 0ms
  2/59. test2 ... passed , time: 1497ms
  3/59. test3 ... passed , time: 593ms

2/15. AnotherTestCaseTest ... passed (2/2), time: 0ms
  4/59. Test4 ... passed , time: 49ms
  5/59. Test5 ... passed , time: 0ms
.....


  Test cases run: 15/15, tests passed: 58/59, Asserts: 100/100, Failures: 0, Exceptions: 0
```

"passed" will be green, skipped - orange, failed - red

the summary line will also have color coding - green if everything passed (or skipped), red if something failed

I don't find any documentation of phpunit classes. Only a quick-guide-type documentation with just few examples:
https://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/extending-phpunit.html

I tried looking at code/comments, but it seems too much work for the simple task I need to do.

**Update:**

What I couldn't find is:

1. How do I run my code after all test cases finish and how do I pass
   the information from the TestListener.
2. How do I replace  phpunit's out (the dots .......) with the one above. Currently my stats are output together with the dots and it looks a bit messy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPunit result output on the CLI not showing test names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180148/phpunit-result-output-on-the-cli-not-showing-test-names)

Answer (score 5):

This packages is what you need.

https://github.com/sempro/phpunit-pretty-print

## phpunit-pretty-print

> Prettify PHPUnit output

[image: phpunit-pretty-print]

#### Installation

```
composer require sempro/phpunit-pretty-print --dev
```

This package requires >=7.0.0 of phpunit. If you're running on version 6, please use version 1.0.3 of this package.

#### Usage

You can specify the printer to use on the phpunit command line:

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit --printer 'Sempro\PHPUnitPrettyPrinter\PrettyPrinter' tests/
```

Optionally, you can add it to your project's `phpunit.xml` file instead:

```
<phpunit
    bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
    colors="true"
    printerClass="Sempro\PHPUnitPrettyPrinter\PrettyPrinter">
```